# Trouble using Python Requests library in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests, serverless

I've got a script to make requests from a website. It works perfectly locally, but whenever I try to run it using Lambda it returns this error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /new (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f00760116d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'
```

The site is a reddit-type forum and I'm trying to access the new posts page.

I'm pretty sure my modules have all imported correctly and I think it's a connection issue, but all my security options are wide open and it still won't connect. I've been left scratching my head at this point. Any help is welcome.

Comment: whether it is in private subnet and have you attached with VPC?

Comment: either your lambda function is not able to reach out to internet because it is deployed in private subnet and there is no NAT or your company is routing your egress requests thru a proxy and you are not setting proxy and/or missing proxy credentials.

Comment: The URL says "/new", which means you're not specifying a domain.  That means it will go to `http://localhost/new`.  Your web server is not running on the lambda machine.  You need to specify the full URL.